# Spring MVC: Append new line to each response

Tags: spring-mvc

Consider simple @RestController, returning a Map:

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> foo() {
    Map<String, Any> map = HashMap<>();
    map.put(...);
    return ResponseEntity(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This works nicely and it returns the Map as JSON.

However, when you `curl` the request in terminal, the cursor stays at the end of the JSON and it is unfortunately uncomfortable working with it. Our previous implementation returned always `\n` at the end of each JSON. Is there a way to make Spring append `\n` as well?

**EDIT**

I tried to implement formatter:

```
private inner class MapFormatter : Formatter<Map<*, *>> {
    override fun parse(payload: String, locale: Locale): Map<*, *> {
        return Gson().fromJson(payload, Map::class)
    }

    override fun print(payload: Map<*, *>, locale: Locale): String {
        return Gson().toJson(payload) + "\n"
    }
}
```

And added in:

```
override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
    registry.addFormatter(MapFormatter())
}
```

Unfortunately it is never called, I guess formatter is meant for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end done via `HttpMessageConverter`:

```
class GsonHttpMessageConverter : AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Map<String, Any?>>(
        MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {

    override fun readInternal(clazz: Class<out Map<String, Any?>>, inputMessage: HttpInputMessage)
            = Gson().fromJson(IOUtils.toString(inputMessage.body, "UTF-8"), clazz)

    override fun supports(clazz: Class<*>) = Map::class.java.isAssignableFrom(clazz)

    override fun writeInternal(payload: Map<String, Any?>, outputMessage: HttpOutputMessage) {   
        outputMessage.body.write(Gson().toJson(payload) + "\n".toByteArray())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Jackson to serialize to a string then append what you want and make that the body of your response entity.

Something like this:

```
//Somewhere in the class fields
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> foo() {
    Map<String, Any> map = HashMap<>();
    map.put(...);
    return ResponseEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(map) + "/n", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However the correct answer would be to have what ever you're using to parse the JSON display it as you would like. Because now you're going to have to add all this complexity.

Another solution would be to 'pretty print' the JSON by setting a pretty printer: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setDefaultPrettyPrinter(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.PrettyPrinter).

Also if you're going to do this, look into setting this at the spring level using something like this where you are building your controllers / services:

```
//Need to look at the documentation and figure out how to set this.    
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer mapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> jacksonObjectMapperBuilder
}
```

Comment: I am looking for some kind of general solution, meaning a `@Configuration` or `Filter`, that would handle this. Your final part is what I am looking for, but still not sure, how to implement this.